# como puedo insertar eventos de fullcalendar guardados en sql

Tags: php, mysql, fullcalendar

En una base de datos tengo la info de unos eventos pero quiero añadirlos automaticamente cuando me meta en la página del calendario.
El problema es que me da un error y no se solucionarlo.
mi intncion es que se añadan eventos por otro lado y desde el calendario se puedan visualizar todos.
El Error es el siguiente:

```
index.php?acc=calendario:73 [Violation]'DOMContentLoaded' handler took 289ms
[Violation]Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 46ms
main.js:6476 GET http://localhost/xampp/App-produccion/App%20produccion%202.8/calendario/cargarevento.php?start=2021-09-26T00%3A00%3A00%2B02%3A00&end=2021-11-07T00%3A00%3A00%2B01%3A00 404 (Not Found)
requestJson @ main.js:6476
fetch @ main.js:6517
fetchSource @ main.js:6105
fetchSourcesByIds @ main.js:6093
fetchDirtySources @ main.js:6076
addSources @ main.js:6068
initEventSources @ main.js:6019
CalendarDataManager @ main.js:6941
Calendar @ main.js:9635
(anónimo) @ index.php?acc=calendario:77
main.js:6126 Request failed {message: 'Request failed', xhr: XMLHttpRequest}
(anónimo) @ main.js:6126
(anónimo) @ main.js:6520
xhr.onload @ main.js:6470
load (asincrónica)
requestJson @ main.js:6451
fetch @ main.js:6517
fetchSource @ main.js:6105
fetchSourcesByIds @ main.js:6093
fetchDirtySources @ main.js:6076
addSources @ main.js:6068
initEventSources @ main.js:6019
CalendarDataManager @ main.js:6941
Calendar @ main.js:9635
(anónimo) @ index.php?acc=calendario:77
```

Y estos son los codigos:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Calendar</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link id="logonsgs" rel='icon' type="image/ico" href='web/img/produccion.ico' />
    <!-- CSS   -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="librerias/fullcalendar/main.css" media="screen,projection" /><!--  Scripts-->
    <script src="web/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="web/js/material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="web/js/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="web/js/jquery-confirm.js"></script>
    <script src="web/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="web/js/dataTables.material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="librerias/jsPDF/jspdf.min.js"></script>
    <script src="librerias/jsPDF/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
    <script src="librerias/fullcalendar/main.js"></script>
    <script src="librerias/fullcalendar/locales-all.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="librerias/fullcalendar/locales/es.js"></script>-->
</head>

<body>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
<style>
        html,
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        #calendar {
            max-width: 1100px;
            margin: 40px auto;
        }
    </style>



    <script>

        var today = 2021-10-07;
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
            

            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
                initialDate: today,
                headerToolbar: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
                },
                locales: 'es',
                events: "cargarevento.php"

            });

            calendar.render();
        });
    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

y el siguiente es el que supuestamente llama los datos:

También es donde se me conecta a la base de datos y es llamado por el codigo anterior.
Aquí lo que hago es generar una array para luego pasarlo al anterior, despues debería hacer un bucle para poder enviar todos los registros

```
<?php

$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db   = 'produccion';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$port = "3306";
$charset = 'utf-8';

$options = [
   \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
   \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
   \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset;port=$port";
try {
    $pdo = new \PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
}
$data = array();

$query = "SELECT PID, INICIO, FIN FROM calendario ORDER BY PID";

$statement = $pdo->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();

foreach($result as $row)
{
$data[] = array(
 'title'   => $row["PID"],
 'start'   => $row["INICIO"],
 'end'   => $row["FIN"]
);
};

?>
```

Muchisimas gracias.

Comment: Por favor, mostrá el error _como texto, con formato_. [Mostrar los errores como imagen es mala idea](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/).

Comment: @padaleiana ya esta